# What & How does this line of code work: {message:0:1} {message:23:17}

Tags: macos, bash, diff

Would love for someone to help educate me on this line of code.

using `diff` command to compare two files which somehow allows for other commands such as `message:0:1` and `message:23:17` to access it's results.

How does this work?

```
message=$(diff previousscan.txt scan.txt | grep 192)

#get first char which indicates if the host came up or went away
iostring="${message:0:1}"

#get first ip-number from the list
computer="${message:23:17}"

#show ip-number in notify if host came up
if [ "$iostring" = \> ]; then
        notify-send "$computer online"
        fi
#show ip-number in notify if host went away
if [ "$iostring" = \< ]; then
        notify-send "$computer offline"
        fi
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$message` is not a command; it is a variable which holds the *output* of the diff command.  The later lines reference substrings; `${message:0:1}` is the first character (1 character starting at offset 0) of whatever is stored in `$message`.

A simple example to show the substring mechanism:

```
$ message="abcdefghijklmnop"
$ echo ${message:0:1}
a
$ echo ${message:7:3}
hij
```

The construction `foo=$(bar)` runs the command `bar` in a subshell, and places the output you would normally see in your terminal if you simply ran the command `bar` in the variable `$foo`.